# how to make all contents for a vis.js timeline shown in the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vis.js

I am using vis.js timeline chart and all the item content showing on the right side. But when some of the contents have a lot of text, not all content are showing on the chart. I am wondering 
(1) if there are anyway to calculate the content length and reset the width of the chart.
(2) if it possible to let the last set of item contents align left instead

Thanks for any advice

The problem is that some of contents on the right side not showing on the chart
[image]

Here is the code

```
 var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, className:'item4', content: 'item 1', start: '2016-04-10'},
    {id: 2, className:'item5', content: 'item 2', start: '2016-04-10'},
    {id: 3, className:'item4', content: 'item 3', start: '2016-04-10'},
    {id: 5, className:'item4', content: 'item 5', start: '2016-04-18'},
    {id: 6, className:'item5', content: 'item 6', start: '2016-04-18'},
    {id: 7, className:'item4', content: 'item 7', start: '2016-04-18'},
    {id: 8, className:'item5', content: 'item 8', start: '2016-04-18'},
    {id: 9, className:'item4', content: 'This item has long title', start: '2016-04-25'},
    {id: 10, className:'item5', content: 'item 10', start: '2016-04-25'},
    {id: 11, className:'item6', content: 'item 11', start: '2016-04-25'}
  ]);

    var options = {
     showCurrentTime: false,
     align: 'left',
     moveable: false,
     orientation: {axis: 'both', item: 'top'}, 
     height: 400,
     margin: {
         axis: 100
    }
  };
  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gbdjbdhv/30/